# Implementing my own leap year class in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm doing some of the exercises over on [exercism.io](http://exercism.io) and for the current one we need to implement our own leap year class (and ignore Ruby's built in feature). Tests are provided and I'm having trouble getting all of them to pass.

To summarise a leap year is any year that is divisible by four EXCEPT if that year is divisible by 100 UNLESS it's also divisible by 400. Here's what I have so far:

```
class Year
  def self.leap?(year)
    if (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)
      return "Yes, #{year} is a leap year"
    else
      return "No, #{year} is not a leap year"
    end
  end
end
```

The tests that are failing are for 1900, 1997, and 1998. It's not a very large file so here's the test fixtures:

```
class YearTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_leap_year
    assert Year.leap?(1996), 'Yes, 1996 is a leap year'
  end

  def test_non_leap_year
    refute Year.leap?(1997), 'No, 1997 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_non_leap_even_year
    refute Year.leap?(1998), 'No, 1998 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_century
    refute Year.leap?(1900), 'No, 1900 is not a leap year'
  end

  def test_fourth_century
    assert Year.leap?(2400), 'Yes, 2400 is a leap year'
  end
end
```

I'm not entirely convinced my logic is sound so any help at all would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is Year.leap? should return true or false, not return a string, according to your tests.

```
class Year
  def self.leap?(year)
    (year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 == 0) || (year % 100 != 0 && year % 4 == 0)
  end
end
```

Your tests will now pass.

The `assert` is looking for a truthy response, `refute` is looking for a falsy response.

We could've left the original code more intact, but saying...

```
if (condition_to_test) == true
  return true
else
  return false
end
```

is more succinctly rendered with just

```
condition_to_test
```

That will automatically return `true` or `false` as appropriate.

Comment: yeah, that was the real problem :)

Comment: The tests were provided so I don't really want to edit them. Are there any changes I could make to the code instead?Maybe I've been looking at this too long but I'm struggling to wrap my head around the logic.

Comment: Ah, right... my answer's wrong, sorry.  Let me fix it now.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. I had internet issues. Thanks for explaining, this makes so much more sense now!

Answer (score 3):

```
class Year
  def self.leap?(year)
    return "Yes, #{year} is a leap year" if (year % 400).zero?
    return "No, #{year} is not a leap year" if (year % 100).zero?
    return "Yes, #{year} is a leap year" if (year % 4).zero?
    return "No, #{year} is not a leap year"
  end
end
```

or

```
class Year
  def self.leap?(year)
    yes, no = "Yes, #{year} is a leap year", "No, #{year} is not a leap year"
    return yes if (year % 400).zero?
    return no if (year % 100).zero?
    return yes if (year % 4).zero?
    return no
  end
end
```

Comment: You forgot the most common case.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. I completely missed that. Ahaha.

Comment: Unfortunately the tests still fail on 1997, 1998 and 1900 :(

Answer (score 0):

Following your description it should look like this

```
if year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0)
  return "Yes, #{year} is a leap year"
else
  return "No, #{year} is not a leap year"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This one finds the leap years within a range of years.

```
(start_year..end_year).each do |year|
  next if year % 4   != 0
  next if year % 100 == 0 && year % 400 != 0
  puts year
end
```